# Bootstrap Web Template: How to stick the footer element to the bottom of the page?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, footer

What I want seems to be simple but I cannot achieve it! :(

I am trying to modify and use the Web template example given [here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_temp_webpage&stacked=h). However, there are a few problems:

First, I want the footer to be at bottom of the page at all times. In the given example, the footer looks like a footer at the bottom of the page because it's only using a fraction of the browser. However, if you run the code as an independent page, you see it is not stuck to the bottom.

Second, I also don't like the below line. I don't want to specify a height.

```
.row.content {height: 450px}
```

How I can achieve both at the same time?

Comment: What is the problem with footer? It is responsive. For this purpose you can't fixed your footer.

Comment: Height:auto or height:10%. footer{position:fixed; bottom:0px}

Comment: @Black Bird My content is fixed and it'd be great if I can have the footer stuck to the page's bottom.

Comment: Then why you are using bootstrap? You can normally do it by giving fixed height.

Comment: @Jonasw not working :(

Comment: @BlackBird Well, I still want the page to be responsive. I'd like it to be seen consistent across different browsers; although the contents are not growing. In other words, I want to allocate always 80% of the height for the main content, 10% for the header and 10% for the footer, etc. But changing of the resolution, shouldn't impact the view.

Comment: @RGo: that was just an example. Is your footer a real <footer> ?

Comment: @Jonasw Yes, I am trying to modify exactly same example. That fits to my purpose other than the mentioned issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question has been asked many times but here's the code anyways:

```
footer {
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.row.content {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: How can I get rid of `.row.content {height: 450px}`?

Comment: use  .row.content {position: fixed; height: 100%;}